# JOOQ Insert List of records

Tags: java, jooq

Currently i am mapping from list of pojos to Record, and i want to be able to insert multiple rows at once. how can i do that in JOOQ with one transaction?

```
 List<Record> recordList = receiverList.stream().map(r -> {
        return dslContext.newRecord(Table, r);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have tried put the list in the "values", but getting exception "The number of values must match the number of fields"

```
dslContext.insertInto(Table).values(recordList);
```

Comment: The `values(Collection)` method is meant to be used for a collection of fields or values for single record insertions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is because .values(...) is waiting for field values not Record.

Maybe you can do [a batch execution](http://jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/batch-execution-for-crud/) :

```
dslContext.batchInsert(recordList);
```

As Lukas mentioned it, it will execute it in a single jdbc statement which is atomic

Answer (score 4):

instead of batchInsert you can also do:

```
var insertStepN = dslContext.insertInto(Table).set(dslContext.newRecord(Table, recordList.get(0));
for (var record : recordList.subList(1, recordList.size()) {
  insertStepN = insertStepN.newRecord().set(dslContext.newRecord(Table, record));
}
insertStepN.returning().fetch().into(YourClass.class);
```

this way you can get the inserted values back using returning(), which you won't get with batchInsert().

Comment: Will this be in a single transaction?

Comment: @tuk yes, that is the point here

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is to pass values for each record separately
But all records will be inserted in one sql statement

```
var insertValuesStep = dslContext.insertInto(
    Table,
    Table.column1,
    Table.column2
);
for (ProcessStatRecordEntity record : records) {
    insertValuesStep.values(
        record.field1(),
        record.field2()
    );
}
var savedRecords = insertValuesStep.returning().fetchInto(Record.class);
```